# Stop the looping at the end of the selector list in WP7 looping selector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, wpf-controls, windows-phone-7.1

My doubt is, is there any way to stop the looping selector from looping when it reaches the end of the list. Suppose the List has 10 items may be 1,2,3,4...10, so when after scrolling once u reach the end of the list i.e, 10 then it shouldn't let u loop.. it should change the direction of flow of the looping selector. Is it possible?..

```
  public void DisplayCatalog(string[] ServiceDisplayName, string[] WheelDisplayName, BitmapImage[] ServiceIcons, WidgetBean[] ServiceBeanList, WidgetBean[] WheelBeanList)
    {
        updateUI();
        DisplayNames.Clear();
        int idIndex = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < WheelDisplayName.Length; j++)
                {
                    string disp1 = WheelDisplayName[j];
                    if (!Utils.isNullString(disp1))
                    {
                        DisplayNames.Add(new ItemList() { WidgetName = disp1, ID = (idIndex + 1) });
                        idIndex += 1;
                    }
                }
this.selectorLeft.DataSource = new ListLoopingDataSource<ItemList>() { Items = DisplayNames, selectedItem = DisplayNames[Index] };
```

corresponding xaml:(am using a horizontal looping selector)

```
 <loop:LoopingSelector
            x:Name="selectorLeft" VerticalAlignment="Center"  ItemSize="200,68" Height="63"
                              d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Width="450">
            <loop:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="#FF48BA1C" Height="75">
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,12,2,2" Width="Auto" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextAlignment="Center" x:Name="scrollingTextBlock" 
                                   Text="{Binding WidgetName}" FontSize="26" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </loop:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </loop:LoopingSelector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling to find a solution for this problem since a year. Today I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/b79a3e93-18e2-4afc-b7dc-a1a29c72806f). I had to just make one change. and that is...

```
this.selectorLeft.DataSource = new ListLoopingDataSource<ItemList>(WheelDisplayName.Length+1) { Items = DisplayNames, selectedItem = DisplayNames[Index] };
```

The looping selector will loop only if the total number of items are greater than WheelDisplayName+1 if not it will stop looping at the end of the last item.

Comment: could you update the link?  This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Implement ILoopingSelectorDataSource.  return null in GetPrevious/GetNext at the start/end of the list.

e.g. Download latest toolkit, comment out GetNext's return.  Notice now running the sample that it doesn't show any next items and therefore doesn't loop.

```
abstract class DataSource : ILoopingSelectorDataSource
{
    private DateTimeWrapper _selectedItem;

    public object GetNext(object relativeTo)
    {
        DateTime? next = GetRelativeTo(((DateTimeWrapper)relativeTo).DateTime, 1);
        return null;// next.HasValue ? new DateTimeWrapper(next.Value) : null;
    }

    public object GetPrevious(object relativeTo)
    {
        DateTime? next = GetRelativeTo(((DateTimeWrapper)relativeTo).DateTime, -1);
        return next.HasValue ? new DateTimeWrapper(next.Value) : null;
    }
```